# Using parskip with ntheorem in a book

Tags: spacing, theorems, ntheorem, parskip

I am writing a mathematical `book` and would like to use `ntheorem` for theorems. Also, I would like to use `parskip`, because I like these styles of paragraphs more. My problem is that as soon as I include the package `parskip`, the spacing before and after theorems gets changed too. How can one avoid that? I tried to use the commands `\theorempreskip` and `\theorempostskip` to modify my ntheorem. But although these commands are listed in the [official CTAN documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ntheorem/ntheorem.pdf), I always get errors like `undefined control sequence \theorempreskip`.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}                %mathematical expressions
\usepackage{amscd}                  %commutative diagrams
\usepackage{amssymb}                %ams math symbols
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            %german umlauts 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         %UTF-8 compatibility
\usepackage{parskip}                %no indentation at beginning of paragraph
\usepackage[thmmarks,amsmath]{ntheorem}


%Theoremstyles
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{mythmstyle}%
{\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip\labelsep ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]}%
{\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip\labelsep ##1\ ##2\ \normalfont{(##3)}\textbf{\theorem@separator}]} 
\makeatother

%Theorems with mystle
\theoremstyle{mythmstyle}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theoremsymbol{$\blacklozenge$}
%\theorempreskip{\baselineskip}
%\theorempostskip{\baselineskip}

\newtheorem{Def}{Definition}


\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend blandit dolor, vel ultricies erat suscipit sit amet. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis accumsan magna et purus facilisis posuere. 
\begin{Def}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend blandit dolor, vel ultricies erat suscipit sit amet. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis accumsan magna et purus facilisis posuere.
\end{Def}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend blandit dolor, vel ultricies erat suscipit sit amet. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis accumsan magna et purus facilisis posuere. 

\end{document}
%Theoremstyles
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{mythmstyle}%
{\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip\labelsep ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]}%
{\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip\labelsep ##1\ ##2\ \normalfont{(##3)}\textbf{\theorem@separator}]} 
\makeatother

%Theorems with mystle
\theoremstyle{mythmstyle}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theoremsymbol{$\blacklozenge$}
%\theorempreskip{\baselineskip}
%\theorempostskip{\baselineskip}

\newtheorem{Def}{Definition}


\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend blandit dolor, vel ultricies erat suscipit sit amet. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis accumsan magna et purus facilisis posuere. 
\begin{Def}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend blandit dolor, vel ultricies erat suscipit sit amet. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis accumsan magna et purus facilisis posuere.
\end{Def}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend blandit dolor, vel ultricies erat suscipit sit amet. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis accumsan magna et purus facilisis posuere. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example works fine for me even if I uncomment `\theorempreskip` and `\theorempostskip`. Section 2.3.5 of the `ntheorem` documentation indicates that these commands were introduced in version 1.32; older versions handled spacing differently and used the commands `\theorempreskipamount` and `\theorempostskipamount`. Your problem is very likely caused by an obsolete `ntheorem` version; try to either update your TeX distribution or see if the old macros (including "amount" in their name) produce acceptable spacing.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I have to use `\theorempreskipamount´ or update my packages.